# What file is sourced/executed when logging in?

Tags: login

I'm trying to add a command to be executed after logging into ubuntu. Specifically, `xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 0`.

What is the file that is sourced/executed when logging into a user session?

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to `~/.xinitrc` for instance.